# Add some properties for each ArraList entry

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to use ArrayList for example but besides only keeping an entry I want to store additional information: "write-in" time, some flag maybe. I could extend the class I am going to store but I want it to be the list feater. I thought maybe to do something like

```
public class PropertirizedArrayList<E> implements List<E> {

private static class TupleContainer<E>{
    public E mainValue;
    public Long hidingTime;
    public Boolean flag;
}

private ArrayList<TupleContainer<E>> list = new ArrayList<>();

private ArrayList<TupleContainer<E>> delegate(){
    return list;
}
//etc...
}
```

but I think it would be a great problem to reimplement all the List interface methods.

Comment: `but I think it would be a great problem to reimplement all the List interface methods.`. Whats wrong with existing List ?

Comment: Why not just create an ArrayList of those tuple containers? Why do you have to create a new list class at all?

Comment: It is better to have an arraylist object and do the implementation. Otherwise you have to override all the methods

Comment: @tobias_k because a want some sort of incapsulation. To put the work with it inside a list-class. I know I can do like you say.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ nothing wrong. Don't want to write ArrayList from scratch that's it. for example to implement indexOf method i need the inner array and it's private.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `List<TupleContainer<SomeType>>`. I don't see a need to wrap the List with `PropertirizedArrayList`.

And if you do have some good reason to use a wrapper class (such a reason would be additional features that your wrapped list implements), you don't have to re-implement the existing List methods.

You have a List member contained within your class, so you can delegate each method of your class to the list.

For example :

```
public TupleContainer<E> get (int index) 
{
    return list.get (index);
}
```

Or if you don't want to expose TupleContainer :

```
public E get (int index) 
{
    return list.get (index).mainValue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do like this, but in this way this methods are going to be outside this list implementation, right? But I want it to work from the inside, like it's "PropertirizedArrayList" feature. But if I want to use for example contains(...) method (that uses indexOf(...)) the delegation becomes more complicated beacuse inside indexOf uses elementData inner array.

Comment: @fantomasdnb If you need to export `contains`, you could implement it as a call to `list.contains` (which would internally call list.indexOf). You could have a problem if you want to implement contains(E), while your internal list only supports contains(TupleContainer<E>). In that case I would suggest that the internal list would be ArrayList<E>, and the extra data for each list entry would be stored in a Map<E,ExtraData>, where extra data is a class containing the additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
private class TupleContainer<E>{
    public E mainValue;
    public Long hidingTime;
    public Boolean flag;
}

List<TupleContainer<YourType>> list=new ArrayList<TupleContainer<YourType>>();

TupleContainer<YourType> tc=new TupleContainer<YourType>();

tc.mainValue=value;
tc.hidingTime=value;
tc.flag=value;
list.add(tc);
```

Comment: This is actually pretty obvious way to use it.)